# Die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels zu durchqueren, war einfach berauschend

Tags: grammar

"Google Translate" translates

> Die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels zu durchqueren, war einfach berauschend.

as

> To cross the desert on a camel's back, was simply intoxicating.

1.In the translated version, the subject is "to cross", but in the original sentence, the subject seems to be "Die Wüste". Maybe the original meant to say "The desert to be crossed on a camel's back was simply intoxicating"?

2.What role does "," play here?

3.If the translated version conveys the meaning accurately, then why not write it as "zu durchqueren die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels war einfach   berauschend"?

Comment: OT: for a machine translation, the Google translation is splendid. I'm astonished that it recognized the structure in this one.

Comment: Side node: *intoxicating* is not the right word for *berauschend* here. It should be *heady* or *exciting*.

Comment: @splattne think so? I kind of liked the exaggeration, it was almost lyrical. In contrast, "exciting" feels really tame, almost lame :) Do you dislike the accuracy of intoxicating in context, or do you think it's an outright invalid translation?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu On second thought, you may be right. :) I didn't know that *intoxicating* has the exact (2nd) meaning as in German.

Comment: @splattne ah, happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the subject in the German sentence is:

> Die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels zu durchqueren

This is a [*Infinitivgruppe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitivgruppe) and the whole *Infinitivgruppe* is the subject here. (By the German grammar you could consider treating a *Infinitivgruppe* like a subordinate clause. If it was a subordinate clause you would call it *Subjektsatz*.)

The comma here is actually optional. The comma is only required under special circumstances. They are defined as:

> (1) die Infinitivgruppe ist mit um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als eingeleitet:
>   Sie öffnete das Fenster, um frische Luft hereinzulassen. Das Kind rannte, ohne auf den Verkehr zu achten, über die Straße. Statt am Bericht zu arbeiten, vergnügte sich Herbert mit Computerspielchen. Ihr fiel nichts Besseres ein, als zu kündigen. Ihre Forderung, um das noch einmal zu sagen, halten wir für wenig angemessen (siehe auch § 77 (1)). Er, ohne den Vertrag vorher gesehen zu haben, hatte ihn sofort unterschrieben (siehe auch § 77 (6)).
>
> (2) die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Substantiv ab:
>   Er wurde beim Versuch, den Tresor zu knacken, vom Nachtwächter überrascht. Er fasste den Plan, heimlich abzureisen.
>
> (3) die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Korrelat oder einem Verweiswort ab.

To your last question:

> zu durchqueren die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels war einfach berauschend

This sentence is not really correct since in a non-main clause you normally put the verb at the end.

Comment: I think that's not correct. It is **not** a subordinate clause. If it were, your main clause wouldn't have a subject. "war einfach berauschend" is not a correct German sentence. You could say "Es war eifnach berauschend, die Wüste..." but that's a different question and there it were a subordinate clause indeed. Furthermore, the comma **is wrong**. Even in English where a comma is more common after a introducing part (as in my previous sentence where "furthermore" is separated; that would be wrong in German).

Comment: @Em1 Was ist es dann, wenn nicht ein Gliedsatz? Ein Hauptsatz kann es ja wohl nicht sein – das Verb steht an letzter Stelle. Laut Duden Regel 121: "Das Komma steht zwischen Haupt- und Nebensatz; eingeschobene Nebensätze werden von Kommas eingeschlossen <§ 74>.", muss man einen Beistrich setzen. Ein Beispiel von dort: "Dass du wieder gesund bist, freut mich." Hier ist auch "Dass du wieder gesund bist" das Subjekt und es ist ein Beistrich gesetzt. Auch hier kann ich den Gliedsatz nicht weglassen, trotzdem ist dies vollkommen richtiges Deutsch.

Comment: Ok. Ja, in der Tat kann das Subjekt abgetrennt werden. Da war ich etwas zu voreilig. Aber ich glaube wir haben sogar beide recht. Der Infinitivsatz **kann** zur Verdeutlichung durch Komma getrennt werden. Siehe [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/PartAdjInf.html?MenuId=SpellingRules0732). Beispiel dort: "Dich zu verstehen(,) ist nicht immer einfach." Im Duden-Beispiel ist tatsächlich ein Komma notwendig, ich denke nach $75.3. Einzig meine Antwort ist richtig übrigens, wenn der Satz laute: "Das Durchqueren ... der Wüste war..."

Comment: Ein Gliedsatz ersetzt ein Glied des Hauptsatzes. Darum ist der Hauptsatz ohne den Gliedsatz nicht unbedingt ein vollständiger Satz. Anders bei Nebensätzen.

Comment: In jedem Fall ist das Subjekt kein *Satz*, dazu fehlt ihm das finite Verb. Es ist ein erweiterter Infinitiv.

Comment: Why is "zu durchqueren" placed at the last place in the clause? I find it strange to put the verb after the object in a clause.

Comment: @pxc3110 Because in a non-main clause you place the verb at the end. Always.

Comment: @idmean Can I eliminate "zu" from the clause?

Comment: @pxc3110 You could use "durchqueren" as a noun. "Das Durchqueren der Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels war anstrengend." (Without a comma.)

Answer (score 4):

In both languages the subject is the whole part that is before (the optional) comma.

> Die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels zu durchqueren
>     To cross the desert on a camel's back

The subject is **not** only the first word. So the noun phrase "Die Wüste" and the verb "to cross" do not function as a subject alone. Actually, a verb can never function as the subject, unless it is part of a longer phrase as given in this example.

When a infinitive phrase is the subject, the comma is optional. The only purpose of the comma is merely clarification.

The comma is obligatory if you use the pronouns *es* or *das* as subject:

> Es war einfach berauschend, die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels zu durchqueren.
>   Die Wüste auf dem Rücken eines Kamels zu durchqueren, das war einfach berauschend.

The rule that applies is [§75](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling143).

With respect to the word order, you do not apply the word order of your source to the target language. Instead you put the words in the order which is most natural in your target language. German and English do not follow the exact same word order although the standard word order (S-P-O) is indeed identical.

In German I can see only one possible other word order (swapping "Die Wüste" and "auf dem Rücken eines Kamels") but the given one is the most natural one. Not sure about English, but I guess this is the only possible variation.

On a side note:
The comma would be wrong if the sentence were:

> Das Durchqueren der Wüste war einfach berauschend.

Comment: How is it possible to swap "Die Wüste" and "auf dem Rücken eines Kamels"? And why is "zu durchqueren" placed at last? I find it bazzare to put a verb at the last place in a clause.

Comment: @pxc3110: What Google said, except that _intoxicating_ may be too literal and negative. My suggestion is _exhilarating_. (Edit: This was a response to the now-deleted comment asking what the sentence means.)

Comment: @chirlu I have already realized that and edited my comment, can you now see the change?

Comment: @pxc3110: Swapping yields _auf dem Rücken eines Kamels die Wüste zu durchqueren_. Also, you may find the word order bizarre, but German speakers don't.